# Linq Time(7) and TimeSpan Mapping

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to insert a record to my table called `Test` , I'm using the LINQ technique :

The problem is I have a `time` column in my table with type of `Time(7)` but when I try to insert data to table I get this error :

`Operand type clash: bigint is incompatible with time`

this is my `test` table Design in SQL :

[image: Table 'Test' in SQL Server 2012]

My table Implementation in C# :

```
[Table(Name = "Test")]
class TableTest
{
    private int _id;
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, Name = "id", Storage = "_id")]
    public int id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }
    private TimeSpan _time;
    [Column(Name = "time", Storage = "_time")]
    public TimeSpan time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set { _time = value; }
    }
}
```

and here I try to Insert my Record :

```
    DataContext dc = new DataContext(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBTest;Integrated Security=True");

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TableTest t = new TableTest();
        t.id = 1;
        t.time = new TimeSpan(7, 30, 0);
        Table<TableTest> t_insert = dc.GetTable<TableTest>();
        t_insert.InsertOnSubmit(t);
        dc.SubmitChanges();  // error Here !!!!!
    }
```

I've searched every where , All I found was that for mapping `Time()` sql type I should use `TimeSpan` , please Tell me What I'm doing wrong ! thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `ColumnAttribute` needs to include the `DbType` parameter.  Set it to

```
[Column(Storage="_time", DbType="Time NOT NULL")]
```

You can see more at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.dbtype.aspx).