# C# Linq to SQL : Odd type conflict between Time and Bigint

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, timespan, bigint

I'm currently working on a website using Visual Studio 2013 and SQL Server but facing a problem regarding this simple code.
To make it easy, I have a "Player" class with a TimeSpan "clock" field but just can not submit changes to the database due to a type conflict issue. The error message is in French but should be something like:

```
Type conflict: bigint is incompatible with time
```

Here is my (simplified) code:

```
[Table(Name = "Players")]
public class Player
{
    [Column(Name = "clock")]
    public TimeSpan Clock { get; set; }
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, Name = "id")]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
        Clock = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The database function raising the exception :

```
public class Database : DataContext
{
    public Table<Player> Players;

    public void AddPlayer()
    {
        Player p = new Player();
        Players.InsertOnSubmit(p);
        SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

And the related SQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Players] (
    [id]            INT         IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [clock]         TIME        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Players] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);
```

I just can not understand what is going on, I even tried to replace the "TimeSpan" type by "DateTime" in Player class and table, and it works perfectly fine. There is definitely an issue with TimeSpan.

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Check answers here. Possible duplicate of [What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000)

Comment: Change column type to BigInt and store `TimeSpan.Ticks` property. When you want to get TimeSpan from database use `TimeSpan.FromTicks(value)`.

Comment: Yes I already read this topic but since I don't need to store values > 24:00:00 I guess it would be a waste to change the database type... However, if there is no other way, I will actually do this way. If there is no other choice but to change "time" into "bigint", then what is the point of having an SQL "time" type ?

Comment: Time is not the same thing as TimeSpan. Time is a time of day only.

Comment: I see, thanks for your explanation. So, since that's exactly what I would need, is there any c# type which would correspond exactly to the time of day (and consequently storable as SQL "time") ? Or do I need to do as explained and use BigInt for the Ticks ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linq Time(7) and TimeSpan Mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16429622/634824)